# Boost asio async_accept works under Windows but fails under FreeBSD. What's wrong?

Tags: c++, windows, boost-asio, freebsd

EDIT: Looks like it's not my code but the build environment. That's both good and bad because now I know that the code is OK but have no idea how to debug the environment. Any suggestions here? Bear in mind that I do not have admin privileges on this computer.

I'm stuck trying to make simple code work under FreeBSD. It's a call to `async_accept` from Boost 1.64 asio that does not behave. Same code works fine under Windows but under FreeBSD it accepts the client connection (the connect call on the client end succeeds) but never calls its handler. Not even sure how to approach this. (Note that unlike other related questions I DO call `io_service.run()`) Please help.

Self contained code that shows the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ph = asio::placeholders;
namespace sys = boost::system;
using asio::ip::tcp;

static void accept_handler(const sys::error_code& error)
{
    // THIS IS NEVER CALLED UNDER FREEBSD
    if (error)
        std::cout << "failed to connected to server" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "connected to server" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: accept_test <port> <1 for async and 0 for sync accept>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), atoi(argv[1])));

    std::cout << "waiting for server connection ";
    tcp::socket sock(io_service);

    if (argv[2][0] == '1')
    {

        //THIS WORKS UNDER WIN BUT DOESN'T CALL HANDLER UNDER FREEBSD
        std::cout << "using async accept..." << std::endl;
        acceptor.async_accept(sock, boost::bind(&accept_handler, ph::error));
    }
    else
    {
        //THIS WORKS FINE UNDER BOTH WIN AND FREEBSD
        std::cout << "using sync accept..." << std::endl;
        sys::error_code error;
        acceptor.accept(sock, error);
        if (error)
            std::cout << "failed to connected to server" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "connected to server" << std::endl;
    }

    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To the close-voter: this is an excellent question, relevant to others and with a SSCCE. It doesn't get more relevant than this.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect an issue with your build environment. Both sync and async work on:

- FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT (GENERIC) #0 r319859: Mon Jun 12 19:37:22 UTC 2017
- FreeBSD clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final 297347) (based on LLVM 4.0.0)

  ```
  Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd12.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /usr/bin
  ```
- Boost 1.64.0 (from ports)

Built using

```
# clang++ -std=c++11 -o test -isystem /usr/local/include/ ./test.cpp -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_system
```

Resulting binary:

```
# ldd test
test:
        libboost_system.so.1.64.0 => /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.64.0 (0x80083c000)
        libc++.so.1 => /usr/lib/libc++.so.1 (0x800a3f000)
        libcxxrt.so.1 => /lib/libcxxrt.so.1 (0x800d06000)
        libm.so.5 => /lib/libm.so.5 (0x800f24000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x801151000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x801367000)
        libthr.so.3 => /lib/libthr.so.3 (0x80172e000)
```

[image]

### Rough instructions for build env:

```
vagrant init freebsd/FreeBSD-12.0-CURRENT
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
vagrant ssh
su
pkg install lang/clang-devel
pkg install devel/boost-all
# copy test.cpp
```

Comment: Added instructions to reproduce the test environment on virtualbox

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're running Boost 1.57 or earlier. The kqueue reactor was broken in some releases with exactly the symptoms you are seeing. You should upgrade to a later version. It works fine with 1.59 on FreeBSD for me.

Comment: I use boost 1.64

Comment: @Paul Your build environment issue may that you have an earlier version of boost in your include search path. Check the -I options to the compiler, then look in those directories to confirm that the boost version. Also check whether someone has installed an earlier version of boost under /usr/include.